# Flutter: extension methods aren't recognized

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

I'm trying to add extension method to `BorderRadius` which apply rounded corner to a `container`
the extention code:

```
extension on BorderRadius{
  static get r10 => const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10));
}
```

and here is how I used it on the container:

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: width * 0.7,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.r10,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [_buttonColor, Colors.purple]),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black87, blurRadius: 5)
            ]),
        child: Text(_lable))
```

The problem is the `r10` method is not among the suggestions of the `BorderRadius` class and isn't recognized.

Comment: Is this extension in the same file where you are using it?\

Comment: no, but is correctly imported.

Comment: Static members/methods in extensions don't add the static members/methods to the class being extended. Instead they are associated with the namespace of the extension itself. For example, if you add a name to the extension such as `extension BorderRadiusExtension on BorderRadius { ... }`, you can then call `BorderRadiusExtension.r10`. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/723

Answer (score 0):

You are using extension on `BorderRadius`. In order to use on value. you need to provide `BorderRadius` 1st, then you will be able to use it.

Like here using on zero BorderRadius.

```dart
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero.r10,
```

```dart
extension on BorderRadius {
  BorderRadius get r10 => const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10));
}
```

Now as way you where using, you can create a custom class and static variable.

```dart
class MyBorderRadius {
 static BorderRadius get r10 => const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10));
}
```

And use case

```dart
borderRadius: MyBorderRadius.r10,
```

Comment: unfortunately this `borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero.r10` doesn't work.

Comment: does your extension include on the same file, If not make sure to import it

Comment: it is in a separated file and imported where the `container` file.

Comment: import that file on your use cases file. if you are getting blue light, click on and if it shows the import file name, click on it. else do it manullay like `import: ''lib\yourPath...'`

Comment: it is imported like this `import '../../theme/extentions.dart';` and when I press `CTRL + Lift Click` it takes me to the extensions file.

Comment: OK,does it solve issue now?

Comment: no still dose not work

Comment: Can you recheck your extension `BorderRadius get r10 => const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10));`

Answer (score 0):

This extension is private which means you can't use it from outside the file where you created it.

To make it global, this is what you need to do

```
extension BorderRadiusExt on BorderRadius {
   static get r10 => const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10));
}
```

You can't import something that is private and be able to use it.
This you have here is an anonymous extension.

To learn more refer to this article.

https://wilsonwilson.dev/articles/dart-extension-methods

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Name for your extension so the IDE can detect and import that extension for you. Like here I give the name  `MyExtenstion`  you can add any name you want

```
extension MyExtenstion on BorderRadius{
  static get r10 => const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10));
}
```